# How to reload select tag options at the onClick event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to reload dropdown textfield options at the onClick event. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexanderbulatovick/4kfsq31w/1/)

html

```
<select id='1' onClick='createOpts(this)'>" + "
    <option>None</option>" + "</select>
```

js

```
function createOpts(that) {
theOptions = "<option>Test</option>";
that.find("option").remove().end().append(theOptions); 
}
```

Why doesn't it reload the options ?

Comment: Because you are trying to use jQuery in vanilla javascript. Add a reference to jQuery, then use `$(that).find....` BTW you also shouldn't start element IDs with a number as in your `id='1'`, it is technically invalid and can caue some code to not work

Comment: Also your HTML has two `" + "` in it, which are used to concatenate strings in javascript and unnecessary in HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these are contributing to your problem:

- You didn't select jQuery in the fiddle.
- createOpts isn't global because the code is run in the onLoad handler.
- `that` refers to the `<select>` element, you need to pass it to jQuery first, e.g. `$(that).find('option')...`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong here.

1. `that` needs to be a jQuery selector (you also need jQuery, assuming you have it in your page and just forgot it in jsfiddle)
2. You are trying to concatenate strings in HTML
3. `theOptions` is not initialized or declared.  When you try to concatenate something to nothing (undefined), you'll get a `ReferenceError`.

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/0juop4wp/1/